# Listening for SIP on multiple ports within one application with Qt and pjsip

Tags: c++, qt, sip, pjsip

I am trying to listen for SIP messages on multiple ports within my Qt console-based application. I am simply creating multiple objects of my class *proxy*.

Sample example of proxy.cpp:

```
proxy* thisProxy;
proxy::proxy(quint16 port, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent), portFromConfig(port)
{
    thisProxy = this;
    thread = new QThread(this);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(start()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    this->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();
}

void proxy::start()
{
    pj_status_t status;
    pj_caching_pool caching_pool;
    pj_sockaddr_in sockaddr;
    pj_str_t ourAddressFromConfig;

    pj_thread_desc initdec;
    pj_thread_t* thread = 0;

    if (!pj_thread_is_registered() && pj_thread_register("PJ_THREAD", initdec, &thread ) != PJ_SUCCESS)
        return;

    pjsip_module proxy = {
        NULL,
        NULL,
        pj_str("proxy"),
        -1,
        PJSIP_MOD_PRIORITY_UA_PROXY_LAYER,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &onReceivedRequest,
        &onReceivedResponse,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    };

    pj_log_set_level(4);

    //initialize pj
    status = pj_init();
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        qDebug() << "pj_init failed";
        return;
    }

    //initilaize pjlib_util
    status = pjlib_util_init();
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        qDebug() << "pjlib_util_init failed";
        return;
    }

    //initialize caching pool
    pj_caching_pool_init(&caching_pool, &pj_pool_factory_default_policy, 0);

    //create the endpoint
    status = pjsip_endpt_create(&caching_pool.factory, NULL, &endpoint);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        qDebug() << "pjsip_endpt_create failed";
        return;
    }

    //specify our socket
    ourAddressFromConfig = pj_str(addressFromConfig.toLatin1().data());
    sockaddr.sin_family = pj_AF_INET();

    if (ourAddressFromConfig.slen)
        pj_inet_aton(&ourAddressFromConfig, &sockaddr.sin_addr);
    else
        sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;

    sockaddr.sin_port = pj_htons((pj_uint16_t) portFromConfig);

    //start the socket
    status = pjsip_udp_transport_start(endpoint, &sockaddr, NULL, 1, &transport);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        qDebug() << "pjsip_udp_transport_start failed";
        return;
    }

    //create the caching pool
    poolt = pj_pool_create(&caching_pool.factory, "UDPproxy", 4000, 4000, NULL);

    //register the proxy module
    status = pjsip_endpt_register_module(endpoint, &proxy);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        qDebug() << "pjsip_endpt_register_module failed";
        return;
    }

    pj_time_val delay = {0, 10};

    while(true)
    {
        pjsip_endpt_handle_events(endpoint, &delay);
    }

    qDebug() << "finished";
}
```

The most interesting thing is that when I create first two instances of *proxy* its working but when I create the third instance my app terminates with these error:

```
server: ../src/pjsip/sip_tel_uri.c:173: pjsip_tel_uri_subsys_init: Assertion `status==0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Backtrace from dumped core:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb777d424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb6e881df in raise () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb6e8b825 in abort () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb6e81085 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0xb6e81137 in __assert_fail () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0x08079344 in pjsip_tel_uri_subsys_init ()
#6  0x08069265 in pjsip_endpt_create ()
#7  0x080569a7 in proxy::start (this=0x8905db8) at ../server/proxy.cpp:93
#8  0x0805f0c1 in proxy::qt_static_metacall (_o=0x8905db8, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=1, _a=0xb3aff270) at moc_proxy.cpp:75
#9  0xb73d4c5d in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /home/dev/Qt/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0xb73d567b in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) () from /home/dev/Qt/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0xb7444ef5 in QThread::started(QThread::QPrivateSignal) () from /home/dev/Qt/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0xb71d7388 in ?? () from /home/dev/Qt/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0xb713ad4c in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#14 0xb6f49bae in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. Could anybody help, please?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: May `endpoint` be a static variable? seems that you're trying to create a tel endpoint but `endpoint` variable's status is not NULL.

Comment: Excuse me, variable endpoint is declared in _proxy.h_ as protected variable like this: `protected: pjsip_endpoint *endpoint;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is that you're creating a new SIP endpoint on every `proxy` instance and, although current documentation states that "theoretically", multiple instance of SIP endpoint is supported, actually, it is not.

More specifically, first time you call `pjsip_endpt_create` three static URI parsers are registered (for `sip:`, `sips:` and `tel:`), second time `tel:` is registered again (there's a check to avoid `sip:` and `sips:` but not for `tel:`) and, when trying to register `tel:` again, at third time, maximum number of URI parsers (4) is overpassed, registration fails and an assertion dumps.

I suggest you to work with only one SIP endpoint, creating a new UDP socket for every `proxy` instance and attaching it to the endpoint by using `pjsip_udp_transport_attach2`

Comment: @IvanBarlog Were you able to check it?

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't try it. I am no longer need this. I thought that I try it anyways but I can't find time for this.